# Error: InvalidParameterException: Task Definition can not be blank

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting below error-
Error: InvalidParameterException: Task Definition can not be blank.
with aws_ecs_task_definition.prod-app-server-task,
on versions.tf line 78, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "prod-app-server-task":
78: resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "prod-app-server-task" {

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "prod-app-server-task" {
  family = "my-ecs-task-family"
  container_definitions = jsonencode(
    [
      {
        cpu         = 0
        environment = []
        essential   = true
        image       = "************.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/terraform"
        logConfiguration = {
          logDriver = "awslogs"
          options = {
            awslogs-create-group  = "true"
            awslogs-group         = "/ecs/prod-app-server-task"
            awslogs-region        = "eu-west-2"
            awslogs-stream-prefix = "ecs"
          }
        }
        mountPoints = []
        name        = "prod-app-server-con"
        portMappings = [
          {
            appProtocol   = "http"
            containerPort = 5000
            hostPort      = 5000
            name          = "prod-app-server-con"
            protocol      = "tcp"
          },
        ]
        volumesFrom = []
      },
    ]
  )
  cpu                = "1024"
  execution_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::************:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  memory             = "2048"
  network_mode       = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = [
    "FARGATE",
  ]
  tags = {
    "ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom" = "ecs-console-v2"
  }
  tags_all = {
    "ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom" = "ecs-console-v2"
  }
  task_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::************:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  runtime_platform {
    cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
    operating_system_family = "LINUX"
  }
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Could it be you haven't saved the file?

Comment: Your error does not make any sense based on the code that you provided. Are you sure that this is your real code?

Comment: yes, this is the real code and file is also saved.

Comment: I have 2 files- .tfstate and .tf file. This code is in .tf

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it works perfectly. So there is no way this code would produce such an error. There must be something else in your setup which you haven't explained in the question.

Comment: I'm not getting actually, I have imported my existing infra setup from aws and trying to create in another region but getting this error while doing terraform plan. I have mentioned same name in ecs fargate service part also

Comment: Are you using a different provider configuration for the additional region you want to deploy it in?

Comment: yes, I have changed the configurations

Comment: I'm using new different account configurations and new access keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/ecs-container-definition/aws/latest for creating container definition

For example

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family = "${var.environment}_${var.service_name}_task"
  container_definitions = module.service_container_definition.json_map_encoded_list
  cpu                      = var.service_cpu
  memory                   = var.service_memory
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  execution_role_arn       = module.ecs_task_execution_role.iam_role_arn
  task_role_arn            = module.ecs_task_role.iam_role_arn

}

module "envoy_container_definition" {
  source          = "registry.terraform.io/cloudposse/ecs-container-definition/aws"
  version         = "~> 0.58"

  container_image = var.image_tag
  container_name  = "name"
  essential       = true

  container_memory_reservation = 256

  user = "1337"

  stop_timeout = 5
  log_configuration = {
    logDriver = "awslogs"
    options = {
      awslogs-group         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.service_logs.name
      awslogs-region        = var.region
      awslogs-stream-prefix = "envoy"
    }
  }

  port_mappings = [
    {
      containerPort = 9901
      protocol      = "tcp"
      hostPort      = 9901
    }
  ]

  healthcheck = {
    retries     = 3
    command     = ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -s http://localhost:9901/server_info | grep state | grep -q LIVE"]
    timeout     = 2
    interval    = 5
    startPeriod = 10
  }


  environment = [
    {
      name  = "LOG_LEVEL",
      value = var.og_level
    }
  ]
  ulimits = [
    {
      softLimit = 15000,
      hardLimit = 15000,
      name      = "nofile"
    }
  ]
}
```